# How to save a file with a BinaryField using Django Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new in Django. please help.
I want to save image in BinaryField using form but it's not working.
instead of upload in media folder, I want to save file Directly in Database using BinaryField.

> Model.py:

```
class serviceDb(models.Model):
    Dev = 1
    QA = 2
    UAT = 3
    Production = 4
    environment_TYPES = (   (Dev, 'Dev'),   (QA, 'QA'), (UAT, 'UAT'),   (Production, 'Production'), )
    application = models.CharField(db_column='Application', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    startdate = models.DateField(null=True)
    expiredate = models.DateField(null=True)
    environment_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=environment_TYPES)
    CSR=models.BinaryField(editable=True)
```

> Form.py:

```
class serviceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    app_attributes = {'oninvalid': 'this.setCustomValidity("Application field is required")', 'oninput': 'this.setCustomValidity("")'}
    startdate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    expiredate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    application = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=app_attributes))
    CSR = forms.FileField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = serviceDb
        fields = ('application', 'startdate', 'expiredate', 'environment_type','CSR' )

        error_messages = {
            'application': {
                'required': ("Application field is required"),
            },
            }
```

Comment: As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) `Although you might think about storing files in the database, consider that it is bad design in 99% of the cases. This field is not a replacement for proper static files handling.`

Comment: I guess you need to convert file to binary before sending it to form, maybe in views.py

Comment: @ruddra This is not I want to. I have to do it , so please help

Answer (score 1):

The BinaryField expects BinaryData, so as @Vaibhav Vishal suggested you may need to convert it on your own.

I've never used the BinaryField so far and you should really consider not saving binary data in the database.

But in your case I suggest trying something like that

```
class ServiceCreateFormView(CreateView):
    template = ...
    form_class = serviceForm  # Should be `ServiceForm` btw.

    def form_valid(self, form):
        uploaded_file = form.files['CSR'].file  # I assume a `InMemoryUploadedFile` instance
        data = uploaded_file.file.read()

        # construct you own instance here using `data`
        self.object = ...

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Please include more informations about your issue. Like a traceback, what exactly is not working, what did you try to resolve it?